# sizeWithAttributes does not take effect

Tags: ios

For some odd reason, following code does not take effect, I changed the size to 20.0, but the size of the text does not increase.  I do not know what might be the cause of the problem. Please help.

```
  [cell.textLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:8.0]}];
```

Answer (score 3):

`sizeWithAttributes` does not "do" anything. It does not "take effect" or "increase" anything. When you call `sizeWithAttributes` you are asking a question. And it gives an *answer* - it returns a size.

It happens that you are throwing that answer away (you never capture it). Thus, your call is pointless, though not formally an error (it is not a compile error or a runtime error to fail to capture a return value - it's just silly).

But the main error you're making is in not reading the docs; you are evidently calling this method with a sheer fantasy idea of what it might do. Don't guess! Read [what the docs tell you](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:).